# Do Traffic Graphs for a GitHub Project include Pages traffic?

Tags: github, analytics, organization

Do the traffic graphs for a given project include the traffic data for the associated Pages site?

I.e. does 
  https://github.com/blackberry/Alice/graphs/traffic

include traffic to
  http://github.com/blackberry/Alice

If not, is that information available anywhere?

Comment: re: Off Topic - GitHub closed its support forum telling folks to use StackOverflow.

Comment: https://github.com/blog/1672-introducing-github-traffic-analytics since January 2014

Answer (score 13):

No, if you want stats for your Pages site you need to use something like google analytics.  GitHub doesn't touch the content of your Pages.

Comment: Thanks.  I had been planning to add Google Analytics anyhow.

Comment: Tried adding Google Analytics but it seems like Google Analytics is trying to scan the root of the subdomain instead of the folder. Made a new question about it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14401370/google-cant-find-analytics-snippet-on-github-pages

Comment: Github don't necessarily need to change the page content to track usage, after all, they handle the traffic so probably can pull the same tricks. Its just a shame they don't, and so we have to buy-in to google stuff.